# python3: two clients sending data to server using sockets

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm working with 3 raspberry pi, one as a server and the two others are clients. What I want to do is to make the clients communicate with the server simultaneously, I don't want to wait for client1 communication to be done in order to launch client2 request to the server (which I succeeded to do). However, I want each client to send different data to server at the same time. I tried to use Sockets and threading, like below.

server code:

```
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from threading import Thread 


# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool
class ClientThread(Thread): 

    def __init__(self,ip,port): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.ip = ip 
        self.port = port 
        print ("[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port)) 

    def run(self): 
        while True : 
            data = conn.recv(2048) 
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print ("Server received data:", data)
            MESSAGE = input("Multithreaded Python server : Enter Response from Server/Enter exit:")
            if MESSAGE == 'exit':
                break
            conn.send(str.encode(MESSAGE))  # echo 

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '' 
TCP_PORT = 9050 
BUFFER_SIZE = 2000  # Usually 1024, but we need quick response 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)) 
s.listen(2)
threads = [] 
list_data=[]


while True: 

    print ("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...") 
    (conn, (ip,port)) = s.accept() 
    data = conn.recv(2048)
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port) 
    newthread.start() 
    threads.append(newthread)
    list_data.append(data) 


for t in threads: 
    t.join()
```

client1 code:

```
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


host = '192.168.0.198' 
port = 9050
BUFFER_SIZE = 2000 
MESSAGE = input("tcpClient1: Enter message/ Enter exit:")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host, port))

while MESSAGE != 'exit':
    s.send(str.encode(MESSAGE))     
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    data = data.decode('utf-8')
    print (" Client2 received data:", data)
    MESSAGE = input("tcpClient2: Enter message to continue/ Enter exit:")
```

client2 code:

```
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

import socket 

host = '192.168.0.198'
port = 9050
BUFFER_SIZE = 2000 
MESSAGE = input("tcpClient2: Enter message/ Enter exit:") 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host, port))

while MESSAGE != 'exit':
    s.send(str.encode(MESSAGE))     
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    data = data.decode('utf-8')
    print (" Client received data:", data)
    MESSAGE = input("tcpClient2: Enter message to continue/ Enter exit:")
```

when i run, i obtain:
 in the server terminal:

```
Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...
[+] New server socket thread started for 192.168.0.197:47012
Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...
[+] New server socket thread started for 192.168.0.196:47886
Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...
```

in client1 terminal:

```
tcpClient1: Enter message/ Enter exit:begin
```

in client2 terminal:

```
tcpClient2: Enter message/ Enter exit:begin
```

It seems like server didn't receive or send any data.

Comment: When you see `New server socket thread started for 192.168.0.197:47012` you have already received data `(conn, (ip,port)) = s.accept() 
    data = conn.recv(2048)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Hikke mentioned in his comment, your server `receives` at two different places. The `conn.recv` call in this code snippet eats up the data that the server receiving thread is expecting. Remove `data = conn.recv(2048)` in your server's main loop:

```
while True: 

    print ("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...") 
    (conn, (ip,port)) = s.accept() 
    data = conn.recv(2048) # <== dont eat the data of your thread here!
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port) 
    newthread.start() 
    threads.append(newthread)
    list_data.append(data)
```